# Populating a ComboBox from a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I recently had quite a lot of fun [answering a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39422495/1188513), and I think I've gone a bit overboard and ended up with a fairly decent way of populating a `ComboBox` from a `Range`.

Given a simple `UserForm` featuring some `ComboBox1` control that I'd want to populate from a `ListObject` on `Sheet1`, the calling/client code looks like this:

> ```
> Option Explicit
>
> Sub Test()
>     With New UserForm1
>         .PopulateFromList Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
>         .Show vbModal
>     End With
> End Sub
> ```

[image: move list, with a hidden ID column]
[image: dropdown with column headings]

(thanks to [Thomas Inzina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6432984/thomas-inzina) for helping with the column headings)

...the `Change` handler in the form's code is just to illustrate that the hidden ID column is effectively being used as the `Combobox.Value`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Not IsNull(ComboBox1.Value) Then Debug.Print ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

And it works!

```
 3            Star Wars
 1            Lord of the Rings
```

Here's the rest of the form's code-behind, the actual code under review - I'm wondering what's the best way to reuse it, I haven't decided whether it's best to extract it into a class module as a utility; with a `WithEvents foo As ComboBox` field I could be having a dynamic control there... it's certainly not practical in the code-behind of some random form though.

I'm not very happy with `GetColumnWidths`, I'm sure there's a better way to do this. As for the `PopulateFromXxxx` methods, ...they're perfect, *aren't they*? ;-)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateFromList(ByVal source As ListObject, Optional ByVal valueColumn As Long = 1, Optional ByVal hasHeader As Boolean = True)
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = source.Range.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = GetColumnWidths(source.Range)
        .ListWidth = IIf(ComboBox1.Width > source.Range.Width, ComboBox1.Width, source.Range.Width)
        .RowSource = source.Name & "[#Data]"
        .BoundColumn = valueColumn
        .ColumnHeads = hasHeader
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub PopulateFromArray(ByVal source As Range, Optional ByVal valueColumn As Long = 1, Optional ByVal hasHeader As Boolean = True)
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = source.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = GetColumnWidths(source)
        .ListWidth = IIf(ComboBox1.Width > source.Width, ComboBox1.Width, source.Width)
        .List = source.Range(source.Rows(IIf(hasHeader, 2, 1)).EntireRow, source.Rows(source.Rows.Count).EntireRow).Value
        .BoundColumn = valueColumn
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetColumnWidths(ByVal source As Range) As String
    Dim cols As Long
    cols = source.Columns.Count

    Dim widths()
    ReDim widths(1 To cols)
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 1 To cols
        widths(col) = source(, col).Width
    Next
    GetColumnWidths = Join(widths, ",")
End Function
```

Is there any way to clean this up? The `.List` assignment in `PopulateFromArray` seems particularly painful.

Comment: I did a spin off of you work to answer this question: [Excel ComboBox - Autosize Dropdown Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624018/excel-combobox-autosize-dropdown-only/39626351?noredirect=1#comment66580189_39626351).  His list was filled by a recordset and not a range.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'd compare the `.width` properties of a control and a range - hear me out.

Let's start with a table of relevant measurements

```
Inch       .5
cm         1.27
Pixel      48
Point      36
Characters 5.38
```

---

#### With a Range

In the excel UI you see two numbers - *characters* and *pixels* when manually adjusting width.

**Characters** being the number of characters with the font (I'm using default here- *calibri 11*) that can fit in the width of the range (yes, that's a ridiculous measurement unit).

In the *Format* menu for a range, the *Column Width* is also **characters**.

In VBA

```
Range.Width = points (Variant Double)
Range.ColumnWidth = characters (Variant Double)
```

`.width` here is giving us *points* which then must be divided by .75 to get to pixels to match the UI.

#### With a Form

The properties of an active x combobox on a form are

```
ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = points (String)
ComboBox1.Width = pixels (Single)
ComboBox1.ListWidth = points (String)
```

#### In the code

```
.ColumnWidths = GetColumnWidths(source.Range)
.ListWidth = IIf(ComboBox1.Width > source.Range.Width, ComboBox1.Width, source.Range.Width)
```

Essentially you set `.ColumnWidths` (String in points) with a String representing points. **Nice**.

Then you compare pixels to points and set `ListWidth` (String in points) with either pixels (as Single) or points (Variant Double).

There's no avoiding this mess, so I would break out another function that returns a String of points.

**Yes, it's needlessly complicated** to do so, unless someone is trying to debug some more complex version of this or you're like me and you hate that excel has done this.

```
    Dim myControlBox As Control
    Set myControlBox = Me.ComboBox1
    With myControlBox
        .ColumnCount = source.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = GetColumnWidths(source)
        .ListWidth = GetListWidth(source, myControlBox)
    End With

Private Function GetListWidth(ByVal source As Range, ByVal myControlBox As Control) As String
    If myControl.Width > source.Width Then
        GetListWidth = myControl.Width * 0.75
        Exit Function
    Else: GetListWidth = source.Width
End Function
```

This answer took me longer to write that I'm willing to admit.

Comment: Very interesting. Interestingly when I dragged the form right under the source table and visually lined up the dropdown with the `ListObject`, the width of the dropdown (and columns) *did* seem to match exactly.

Comment: Yes, it would (and does) work fine as it is, but I could see VBA being a tricky bastard and getting confused at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong about the column heads.  They display properly when you are using `RowSource` but not `List`.

I think that using a custom Type to wrap up the functionality, really cleans up the code.

### Demo

[image]

### Code

```
Type ListSettings
    ColumnCount As Integer
    ColumnWidths As String
    ListWidth As String
    List As Variant
    RowSource As String
End Type

Function getListSettings(Source As Range, Optional ByVal hasHeader As Boolean = True) As ListSettings
    Dim r As Range
    Dim t As ListSettings
    Dim s As String

    For Each r In Source.Rows(1).Cells
        s = s & r.Width & ","
    Next
    'This works because Boolean Logic evaluates to -1 for True and 0 for False.
    Set Source = Source.Offset(Abs(hasHeader)).Resize(Source.Rows.Count + hasHeader)

    With t
        .ColumnCount = Source.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        .ListWidth = Source.Width
        .List = Source
        .RowSource = Source.Address
    End With

    getListSettings = t
End Function
```

### Userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim t As ListSettings
    t = getListSettings(Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Range)

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = t.ColumnCount
        .ColumnWidths = t.ColumnWidths
        .RowSource = t.RowSource
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With

    With ListBox2
        .ColumnCount = t.ColumnCount
        .ColumnWidths = t.ColumnWidths
        .RowSource = t.RowSource
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With

    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = t.ColumnCount
        .ColumnWidths = t.ColumnWidths
        .List = t.List
        .ColumnHeads = True
        If .Width < t.ListWidth Then .ListWidth = t.ListWidth
    End With

    With ComboBox2
        .ColumnCount = t.ColumnCount
        .ColumnWidths = t.ColumnWidths
        .RowSource = t.RowSource
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ListWidth = IIf(.ListWidth > t.ListWidth, .Width, t.ListWidth)
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()
    ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm always reluctant to use `Range.Offset`, but I have to say that it and `Resize` feel "just right". Using the integer representation of the Boolean value might call for an explicit `CInt` conversion call, or an explanatory comment though. But I like how it removes the redundancies in the `.List` assignment.

Comment: @Mat'sMug  Comments are one of my weaknesses. I liked how both of our implementations  turned out.