# Working with a new form instance every time

Tags: object-oriented, vba, form

I have a form that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

It is initialized with a Shortcut from the keyboard. It is in a module:

```
Public Sub ShowMainForm()
    With frmMain
        .Show vbModeless
    End With        
End Sub
```

The form has a button:

```
Private Sub btnRun_Click()
    Call MainGenerateReport    
End Sub
```

The button runs a procedure, called `MainGenerateReport` in a module.

```
Public Sub MainGenerateReport() 
    ' other code;
    Call frmMain.MakeLabel
    ' other code;
End Sub
```

`frmMain.MakeLabel` changes a label in the form with some information:

```
Public Sub MakeLabel()
    Dim c           As Long
    Dim r           As Long
    Me.lbInfo.Visible = checkNumbers
    Me.lbInfo.Clear

    If checkNumbers Then
        With Me.lbInfo
            .ColumnCount = 2
            .ColumnWidths = CStr(Me.lbInfo.Width / 1.8 & ";" & Me.lbInfo.Width / 4)

            For r = 0 To 7
                .AddItem
                For c = 0 To 1
                    .List(r, c) = tblInfo.Cells(1 + r, 3 + c)
                Next c
            Next r
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

At the end, if I want to close the form, I use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. I have a button on the form, `btnExit` and its `cancel` property is set to True:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The problem: According to [VBA best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms#t=201702020940439422077), I should initialize the form like this (and rewrite my `MakeLabel` and the `btnExit_Click` accordingly):

```
Public Sub ShowMainForm()
    With new frmMain
        .Show vbModeless
    End With        
End Sub
```

Is that recommended?

Comment: Why does `MainGenerateReport` need to call `frmMain.MakeLabel`? What's the `other code` doing?

Comment: `MainGenerateReport` is uniting a few excel files together. In the `frm.MakeLabel`, there is information about the total number of rows of the newly created file and other relevant information, for the operation carried out. Something like `Successfully carried out`, `1000 rows are added` etc.

Comment: Would that work if you pass the form as a parameter to the other functions byref, and then access directly the instance you created with new? like MainGenerateReport(ByRef main as Form)

Comment: @fernando.reyes - for `MakeLabel` it would probably work. However, it will not work at the end, when the form stays and displays information. Then it is closed manually by the user - either through the X or through the escape key, which runs currently with `btnExit_Click`.

Comment: @Vityata The way to close every windows from a macro is with the End statement. The End statement will close everything you had open, close files, etc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wt87xba.aspx

Comment: @fernando.reyes, I don't want to close anything. I want to open the form, run the macro and display the results in the form. Then the user is closing the form by himself/herself. I am achieving this quite well. However, if I use `new frmMain.Show vbModeless` I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @fernando.reyes - or are you proposing in stead of `Unload Me` to write `End` and simply to close it like this?

Comment: Just noticed the form is modeless - does it *have* to be? A modal form blocks execution, so the `End With` is only reached after the form gets closed, and if the `With` block holds the object reference then that's when the object gets destroyed. Wouldn't `With New frmMain` just flicker the form for a split second before its instance goes out of scope?

Comment: Actually didn't think about the fact that `with new` is like `using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("file.txt"))` in C#.  And yes, the form has to be modeless - it displays a small summary of the report, thus the users (and mainly me) can browse around the sheets and verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Public Sub ShowMainForm()
>     With frmMain
>         .Show vbModeless
>     End With        
> End Sub
> ```

You don't want that `With` block, it's redundant.

> ```
> Public Sub ShowMainForm()
>     With New frmMain
>         .Show vbModeless
>     End With        
> End Sub
> ```

You don't want to do that with a `vbModeless` form either - the instance will be destroyed quite immediately after being created.

For an object-oriented approach that uses a modeless form, I'd suggest you make the form a member of a dedicated "presenter" class:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents summaryForm As frmMain ' <~ notice WithEvents ..I'll get to it.

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set summaryForm = New frmMain
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set summaryForm = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Show()
    If Not summaryForm.Visible Then summaryForm.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Public Sub Hide()
    If summaryForm.Visible Then summaryForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Now, this "presenter" class shall be responsible for accessing the form; notice how it already hides the implementation detail of the modeless-ness to the outside world.

When the user clicks the `btnRun` button, the form itself shouldn't be responsible for anything - so instead of calling `MainGenerateReport` directly, we'll fire an event to tell the presenter class that it needs to do something about it:

```
Option Explicit
Public Event OnRunReport()
Public Event OnExit()

Private Sub btnRun_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnRunReport
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnExit
End Sub
```

That way the form has no dependencies to other modules, and pretty much zero responsibilities.

Back to the presenter, we can handle these events:

```
Private Sub summaryForm_OnRunReport()
    MainGenerateReport
    Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub summaryForm_OnExit()
    Hide
End Sub

Public Sub Refresh()
    'todo
End Sub
```

This leaves the problem of `MakeLabel`/`Refresh`. I don't know what `tblInfo` is, but I'm pretty sure it's not the form's concern. Really all it needs is some `Range` or `ListObject` that contains whatever information needs to go into that list - and instead of looping to `.AddItem` and explicitly set each `.ListItem`, you could use the control's `.RowSource` property and avoid looping altogether; [this CR Q&A](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140999/23788) shows how.

Once the presenter class is capable of providing a data source for the form's `ListBox` (you'll have to verify it it actually *binds* to the source; if that's the case then you won't even need a *refresh* button, the list would just *update itself*).

That would be the `Refresh` implementation.

The last step is to instantiate the presenter; as long as the presenter instance is alive, the encapsulated form instance lives - there's no need to explicitly `Unload Me` anywhere.

Say you named the class `SummaryPresenter`, then you could have it exist in global scope:

```
Option Explicit
Private presenter As SummaryPresenter

Public Sub ShowMainForm() ' macro attached to shortcut key
    If presenter Is Nothing Then Set presenter = New SummaryPresenter
    presenter.Show
End Sub
```

Since we made the `OnRunReport` handler call `Refresh` after `MainGenerateReport` runs, the procedure no longer needs to call it explicitly. Or, if it *does* need to (hard to tell with just a little `'other code;` comment to work with), then it can do so by calling the `Presenter` object's `Refresh` method:

```
Public Sub MainGenerateReport() 
    ' other code;
    presenter.Refresh
    ' other code;
End Sub
```

---

This makes your code use the same instance of `frmMain` all the time, while separating responsibilities into different [class] modules... which isn't much different from working against the *default instance* in the first place.

But then, everything boils down to *why* you would want a new instance every time - IMO if the form is a modeless "toolwindow" that you can show/hide while working in Excel, then it's objectively better (more efficient) to avoid initializing it everytime you want to show it... just like it's more efficient to avoid initializing the listbox columns everytime you refresh it ;-)

Comment: Impressive! Thanks, I wIll take a better look at it tomorrow :)

Comment: Hi again! :) I have ran it and it seems that sometimes there is an error. The error is in Public Sub Show of clsSummaryPresenter`
On the line -> `If Not objSummaryForm.Visible Then`.
It is because the code checks an object for visibility, which is nothing. The screenshots are the two *.png files in the repository here - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/tree/master/FormWithAnInstanceVBA. I am trying to build some kind of boilerplate for a form for some future projects.

Comment: Actually, I found out when exactly it crashes - if  I close the form with the `X` on the top right corner, the next initialization breaks with the errors I have shown.

Comment: You still need to handle QueryClose and prevent the form from unloading itself.

Comment: Yeah, QueryClose is what I need. I have put the following in clsSummaryPresenter, but it does not even enter the code - http://pastebin.com/NQ68Bpgn

Comment: Form event handlers have to be in the form's code-behind

Comment: I have frmMain, modMain and clsSummaryPresenter. I have tried to put the QueryClose code anywhere, just to get something running on the immediate window. No success so far. Feel free to push in GitHub with anything.

Comment: QueryClose **must** be handled in the userform module. Anywhere else and it's dead code.