# Handling dialog closure in a VBA user form

Tags: vba, event-handling, gui

I already asked a Code Review question about [Working with a new form instance every time](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154270/how-to-work-with-new-form-instance-every-time).

As far as I have decided, that the most important part of the code is to work with the instance of the form and to learn how to handle them properly, I have remade the code (roughly using the code from @Mat's Mug) in a way that I am looking for a type of a boilerplate for forms, that I will probably use later.

Thus, let's start. I have a form, that looks like this:
[image]

Buttons are called `btnStart`, `btnExit` and `lblInfo`.

This is the code behind the `frmMain`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event OnRunReport()
Public Event OnExit()

Private Sub btnRun_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnRunReport
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click()
    RaiseEvent OnExit
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)

    End

End Sub
```

This is the code behind the `modMain`:

```
Option Explicit

Private objPresenter   As clsSummaryPresenter

Public Sub MainGenerateReport()

    Call objPresenter.ChangeLabelAndCaption("Starting and running...", "Running...")
    GenerateNumbers

End Sub

Public Sub GenerateNumbers()

    Dim lngLong         As Long
    Dim lngLong2        As Long

    tblMain.Cells.Clear

    For lngLong = 1 To 3000
        For lngLong2 = 1 To 10
            tblMain.Cells(lngLong, lngLong2) = lngLong * lngLong2
        Next lngLong2
    Next lngLong

End Sub

Public Sub ShowMainForm() 'CTRL+E

    If (objPresenter Is Nothing) Then Set objPresenter = New clsSummaryPresenter
    objPresenter.Show

End Sub
```

This is the code behind the `clsSummaryPresenter`:

```
   Option Explicit

    Private WithEvents objSummaryForm As frmMain

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()

        Set objSummaryForm = New frmMain

    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()

        Set objSummaryForm = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub Show()

        If Not objSummaryForm.Visible Then
            objSummaryForm.Show vbModeless
            objSummaryForm.lblInfo = "Press Run to Start"
            objSummaryForm.Caption = "Starting"
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub Hide()

        If objSummaryForm.Visible Then objSummaryForm.Hide

    End Sub

  Public Sub ChangeLabelAndCaption(strLabelInfo As String, strCaption As String)

    objSummaryForm.lblInfo = strLabelInfo
    objSummaryForm.Caption = strCaption
    objSummaryForm.Repaint

  End Sub


  Private Sub objSummaryForm_OnRunReport()

    MainGenerateReport
    Refresh

End Sub

Private Sub objSummaryForm_OnExit()

    Hide

End Sub

Public Sub Refresh()

    With objSummaryForm
        .lblInfo = "Ready"
        .Caption = "Task performed"
    End With

End Sub
```

What I am not sure (and I did not understand) was how to handle the red `X` in a way that there is no error after it. Thus, I have decided to use the `End`, which seems to work fine.

I have put [the Excel file on GitHub](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/356a594c614cdca3c756d64ebc37a0b1cdbd7cc6/FormWithAnInstanceVBA/Form001.xlsb).  It contains the same VBA code as shown above, I encourage you to first inspect it with macros disabled, as a good security practice with Excel files from the Internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like how your form is no longer concerned with anything other than *being a form*.

#### One More Abstraction Level

I'd go one step further, and encapsulate the controls, so that the *presenter* class doesn't need to know about the implementation details of the form. For example the `ChangeLabelAndCaption` method knows that there's a `Label` control on the form, named `lblInfo`.

The form could expose a property for it instead:

```
Public Property Get InformationText() As String
    InformationText = lblInfo.Text
End Property

Public Property Let InformationText(ByVal value As String)
    lblInfo.Text = value
End Property
```

This adds a little layer of abstraction, so that the presenter no longer needs to care what actual controls are on the form, so if you decide to change the `Label` control for some `Frame` instead, nothing breaks - your code is now independent of the form's implementation details:

```
objSummaryForm.InformationText = strLabelInfo
```

---

#### For Closure's Sake

> ```
> Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)
>
>     End
>
> End Sub
> ```

The `End` keyword is essentially analoguous to this:

[image: nuke]

Sure, that will get your form closed, and everything the VBA runtime has been doing will get released. But it's *a tiny little wee bit* excessive: the `End` keyword literally *ends* execution of all VBA code, right there and then.

The `QueryClose` event is fired just before the form closes, and its parameters give you a handle on the process.

It's just unfortunate that their types are `Integer`.

The `CloseMode` parameter tells you *how* the form is closing; its value is one of the `VbQueryClose` enum values:

- `vbAppTaskManager`
- `vbAppWindows`
- `vbFormCode`
- `vbFormControlMenu`
- `vbFormMDIForm`

The interesting value - the one that means "user clicked the red X button", is `vbFormControlMenu`. The integer value for it is `0`. So you can do this:

```
If CloseMode = 0 Then
```

Or better, this:

```
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
```

And then handle form close yourself.

When the "red X button" is clicked, the form instance is normally destroyed. If the form contains state that the calling code wants to use, if you don't handle `QueryClose` and the calling code looks like this:

```
myForm = New MainForm
myForm.Show vbModal
Debug.Print myForm.SomeProperty
```

Then the last statement will be a runtime error, because `myForm` is `Nothing` at that point.

---

#### The Golden Rule

> *He who creates an object, shall be responsible for its destruction.*

If the form can destroy itself, the calling code is left needing awkward `If myForm Is Nothing` post-conditions to handle the case where it created an object that decided to *hara-kiri*.

A cleaner approach is to *prevent* the form from being able to destroy itself.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

We set the `Cancel` parameter to `True`, thus preventing the destruction of the object, but only when the `CloseMode` flag indicates that the form was closed from the *control menu*. If we didn't call the `Hide` method, the form would simply refuse to close with the "red X button". This is useful for the rare circumstances where you *don't* want a form to be closable by the user.

---

The `QueryClose` handler signature would arguably be much clearer like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(ByRef CloseMode As VbQueryClose, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
```

Unfortunately that signature mismatches the interface declaration, and wouldn't compile. But handling the `QueryClose` event works exactly as if that's what the signature was.

---

#### Hungarian Notation

Your code suffers from the "bad" form of Hungarian Notation. While *Systems Hungarian* is traditionally acceptable for form controls (e.g. `lblInformation`, `txtUserInput`, `btnOk`, etc.; the prefix tells us what *type* of control we're looking at), using it in actual code for everyday variables, makes things messy:

> ```
> Dim lngLong         As Long
> Private WithEvents objSummaryForm As frmMain
> Public Sub ChangeLabelAndCaption(strLabelInfo As String, strCaption As String)
> ```

[**Hungarian Notation was never intended to turn out this way**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) (<~ must read!).

The guy that *invented* Hungarian Notation meant prefixes to describe the *kind* of variable, not their *type*. *Apps Hungarian* actually *does* make the code easier to read and understand, and *makes wrong code, look wrong*:

```
't: measured in twips
'p: measured in pixels

tArea = tHeight * tWidth 'obviously correct
tArea = pHeight * tWidth 'obviously wrong
```

Assuming the same context (twips vs pixels), compare to:

```
'int: integer
'lng: long

lngArea = intHeight * intWidth 'correct?
lngArea = lngHeight * intWidth 'correct?
```

When you prefix an object variable with `obj`, or a string with `str`, an integer with `int`, `lng`, or any other type-prefix, you add zero useful information to its identifier, and make the names read awkwardly.

```
Dim oRange As Range
```

Stop doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will check it with details later. Concerning the Hungarian notation - I am using this here - https://ss64.com/access/syntax-naming-variables.html Before my naming convention was even more brutal, like this: `long_sum_of_variables`, thus I am trying to follow something. What are you using? Do you show anyhow that an `int` is `int` etc?

Comment: Ctrl+i gives me the type of the variable I'm looking at. Or, with Rubberduck, merely selecting it gives me the type of the variable I'm looking at. The type of a variable is utterly irrelevant and encoding it into the identifier name is wasting precious space that could be used to describe its *meaning* and *purpose* instead.

Comment: I have tried the code from above, but I still could not handle the red cross closing. Probably I am missing something small - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/tree/master/FormWithAnInstanceVBA/Form003 but I still get the error. I think that it does not go through the `Hide` in `Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(CloseMode As Integer, Cancel As Integer)` but it still does not indicate it as an error. Any ideas?

Comment: And another question, in a way offtopic - when I click End here -> https://www.wisdomjobs.com/userfiles/image/1%20MS%20ACCESS/CHAPTER1/Figure-1-2-In-this-Access-pop-up-window,-you-can-either-end-the-code.png is it the same as if I write `End`?

Comment: A third question, concerning the question 1 - I have changed the `UserForm_QueryClose` to the following: https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/ea7db4fa046ecfb0e0d79dc9fcbf979e Thus, still the `RED Cross` works different than the `btnExit_Click`. E.g. if I close it through the Red Cross, I get the nasty error, and if I close it through the `btnExit_Click` it works ok. Any idea why? :)

Comment: Indeed, clicking [End] on that dialog has the same effect as executing an `End` statement, or clicking the *Stop* button in the IDE/debugger: the execution context gets terminated immediately. Your code works exactly as intended here, no errors or anything. Not sure what error you're experiencing, but you might want to ask about it on [so] (make sure you include enough details to reproduce the issue, since I can't reproduce it with the form code you have on GitHub).

Comment: Thanks, Mat's Mug! I have this error - `Runtime 2147418105 (80010007) ` - automation error when I try to open the form, after I have closed it from the X. It really seems unbelievably strange, because when I close it from the `Exit` button I am using the same code... but I will probably ask in SO.